# Freewall Js website not found

Tags: javascript, freewalljs

I am using this excelent javascript library.
Since Monday the webpage of the project is not loading:
http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/

Whats wrong?
Is there any other webpage to access the documentation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could try googling it and getting the cached version, until they sort their site out.

Comment: You can try with this link:
http://kombai.github.io/freewall/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I found a webpage that holds the documentation of the freewalljs.
Anyone struggling with the documentation can find it here:
http://www.oboa.on.ca/events/2016/template/index1.html

Answer (score 1):

I can see the root domain http://vnjs.net/ is down.
Alternatively you may visit
[freewalljs](https://github.com/kombai/freewall)

Comment: your are left with few options: (1) learn from the examples https://github.com/kombai/freewall/tree/master/example, or (2) dig in the source

Comment: @Yohanes Gultom I am following your 1st proposal, but unfortunately is not efficient :p